# Pytest-html shows error "unrecognized arguments"

Tags: pytest-html

I have pytest-html installed but I'm getting this error everytime i try to generate a report.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsQW4.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come across same issue, but with a different option. It got resolved by updating pytest version from pytest-5.3.2 to pytest-5.4.3

> python -m pip install --upgrade

This will install latest version of pytest.